# Debugging Node.js express app

Tags: node.js, express

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
    at C:\Users\denman\workspace-nodejs\ExpressNodeUpAndRunning\app.js:112:25
```

I am trying to find out the line number of the error...

is 112 the line number of the app.js file where the error occurred? Then what is 25?

Comment: it is simply meaning that an error is occuring from the 25th letter in the line.and to fix your error,make sure you defined *** of "***.get"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3 components are `sourceFilePath`:`lineNumber`:`columnNumber`.

So the error occurs on line 112, at column 25.